# How to use postfix notation on latex for this

Tags: math-software

$x=\frac{cos t}{1+sin^2 t}$
$y=\frac{sin t cos t}{1+sin^2t}$ ?
I have done it like

cos t 1 sin 2 exp t add div

And

sin t cos t mul 1 sin 2 exp t add div

It gives no output at all .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider writing t ahead of sin or cos ,in postfix notation argument variable comes first .
It will be like

t cos 1 t sin 2 exp add div
 t sin t cos mul 1 t sin 2 exp add div
Execute with this may this helps ! Thanks

Comment: Okay I will execute it this way

Comment: Thanks it works now !

Comment: Try cardioid and folium of decasrtes for more knowledge

Comment: So cardioid's equation is like t cos t cos 2 exp sub and t sin t sin t cos mul sub ??